# Can a peripheral can be connected to multiple centrals?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

From [this book](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/getting-started-with/9781491900550/ch01.html) it says

> A peripheral can be connected to multiple centrals.

can any BLE module do this? More specifically can [bluegiga 112](https://www.bluegiga.com/en-US/products/ble112-bluetooth-smart-module/) do it? If not what are the BLE modules that can work as a peripheral connected to multiple devices?

The same book also states

> Once the connection is established, the peripheral stops advertising and the two devices can begin exchanging data in both directions

so if the peripheral stops advertising how will it accept more connections as mentioned above? How will other scanners detect this peripheral?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I think I read that 4.1 included the addition of the ability to have a peripheral attached to multiple centrals, but 4.0 definitely can't do that.  Also, I doubt there's any device that's actually implemented these recent specification changes.

Comment: Moments ago I had an ESP-32 presenting a heart monitor and connected to two different Android devices, each of which was successfully subscribing to its data.

Answer (score 4):

Tim Tisdall is correct. That solution works for specification 4.1, but not for 4.0. As you mentioned above, you cannot establish a connection with a device that is not discoverable, and since it stops advertising upon connection establishment, it is impossible to have a peripheral connected to multiple centrals.

Answer (score -2):

Any peripheral BLE device can "broadcast" it's attributes/characteristic values in GATT profile. So, any central device interested in the value can potentially "connect" to the BLE peripheral to get that broadcast message. So, that's what i believe is a use case for "A peripheral can be connected to multiple centrals."

I don't think the peripheral stops advertising it's presence just because it's connected to a certain central device. Any device can still see it's presence when it does a scan.

Comment: No, actually the peripheral stops advertising before the central connect it.